# Is there a fix for Mac OS Preview, file opening window not showing on opening the application?

Tags: finder, preview, big-sur

Hello I am using Mac OS 11.2.3 M1 Macbook Air

When I open Preview no window shows up to select a file to open. But when I secondary click on the logo and open a recent file everything works fine. Is there fix for my problem?
P.S. all functions inside preview seems to work but my inner perfectionist is screaming!

Answer (score 1):

If you have un-checked Preview in **System Preferences > AppleID > iCloud Drive Options**, then it won't show the file dialog by default.

Weird, I know, but there you have it.